# Laravel - How to INSERT rows with Reserved Words and dashes

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, reserved-words

I have a `MySQL` table and I can't change the structure because is from Asterisk. Two columns have troubled names and I don't know how to handle it using `Eloquent`.

```
$row = new Extension;
$row->call-limit = $calllimit; 
$row->dynamic = $dynamic;
$row->save();
```

`call-limit` have a dash and `dynamic` is a reserved word.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$row->getAttribute('call-limit');

$row->setAttribute('call-limit', $limit);
```

Comment: Your comment is good because I can use to read, but, I need to insert and update the table:
`Can't use method return value in write context`

Comment: So use setAttribute - would be my first guess ;P

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
$row = new Extension;
$row->fill(array('call-limit' => $calllimit, 'dynamic' => $dynamic ));
$row->save();
```